# How Can I mimic a meta refresh with JS?

Tags: javascript, validation, meta-tags

I tried to do

`<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.php" />');
//]]>
</script>`

but that doesn't validate on strict =[

how can I do that with JS alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
location.href = 'index.php';
```

To refresh the same page:

```
location.reload();
```

To wait 2 seconds before reloading (as `<meta>` can do):

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 2000);
```

Comment: works wonderfully on my site try it out ^.^ 

http://localhost/INTN2201/lab/index.php

use that site with JS enabled then disable it and refresh then enable it again and refresh ^.^

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but obviously I cannot access a site on your localhost :) Thanks!

Comment: http://opentech.durhamcollege.ca/~intn2201/brittains/labs/

there we go correct link